# RandomForestClassifier prediction_proba(X) outputs results only for one category

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am running some simulations using `RandomForestClassifier` to classify between 2 categories, and I am using the function below to debug:

```
def predict_proba(self, X):

    print(X.shape)

    pred = self.clf.predict_proba(X)

    print(pred.shape)

    pred = pred.T[1]

    print(pred.shape)

    return pred
```

This routine runs several times as I have split my data, and I get the follow outputs for the printing `.shape` routine I've coded above.

```
(62, 93)
(62, 2)
(62,)

(62, 93)
(62, 2)
(62,)

(62, 93)
(62, 2)
(62,)

(62, 93)
(62, 1)
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

My question is why does `prediction_proba(X)` most of the times output a shape of `(62, 2)` (as expected) and other time outputs a shape of `(62, 1)`?

**EDIT**

I think I understood it, it seems like that classifier was trained with only one category, as I wasn't using Stratified KFold or something like it.

Comment: It's something to do with the shape of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the issue. It was happening because I split my data into chunks in a manner that some of these chunks only had 1 category out of the possible 2, so the `RandomForestClassifier` would `.fit()` in only 1 category.

I solved it using `sklearn.model_selection.StratifiedKFold`.